# UEFI refuses to remember BootOrder value and creates additional ones every boot

Tags: ubuntu, uefi

I have an issue with an HP Elitebook 8770w, which I am using as a Linux box for various purposes. It runs Ubuntu 20.04 which also acted up during installation and so I was forced to install it from a Ubuntu live server CD, because the desktop CD did not work at all (dropped into emergency shell of initramfs, because it allegedly could not find the CD off of which the kernel had just booted). By installing a DE, I basically brought it into shape as a desktop Linux.

After the initial messages, around the point where one would normally get to see GRUB (unless hidden), I get the following warning/error message:

```
System BootOrder not found. Initializing defaults.
Creating boot entry "Boot0002" with label "ubuntu" for file "\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi"
```

At that point it continues booting into Ubuntu seemingly fine. However, that `"Boot0002"`, which is probably familiar to those of you who ever played with `efibootmgr`, gets incremented with each subsequent boot. And so after a few boots it looks like this (`efibootmgr -v`):

```
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0005
Boot0000* Notebook Hard Drive   BBS(HD,^B^?ÿ^D,0x0).......................................................................
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,3794ad09-e791-41d6-4fed-deadbe3fc20c,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0002* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,3794ad09-e791-41d6-4fed-deadbe3fc20c,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0003* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,3794ad09-e791-41d6-4fed-deadbe3fc20c,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0004* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,3794ad09-e791-41d6-4fed-deadbe3fc20c,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0005* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,3794ad09-e791-41d6-4fed-deadbe3fc20c,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
```

So I do the `efibootmgr -B -b 000X` routine, where `X` is 2..5 (or even 1..5), but next boot around I will have a fresh entry referring to the Ubuntu/GRUB UEFI shim.

Resetting (`-O`) or setting (`-o`) the `BootOrder` also doesn't seem to stick, so I am at a loss at what's going on here and how to fix it. Sure, I could write a `cron`-job to clean up those excess `Boot000X` entries, but I'd rather fix the cause than the symptom.

Quite frankly I didn't dare removing `Boot0000` because I don't know whether I can recover from that in case the UEFI doesn't. On a Dell machine I have this wouldn't be an issue, but on this machine there doesn't appear to be a means to configure the UEFI side of the boot menu quite as much. The 8770w is out of support and has been for a few years by now, so this is why I'm asking here.

**NB:** UEFI version is the latest for this model, dating to spring 2019.

Comment: See if the solutions here help : [system bootOrder not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042747/system-bootorder-not-found).

Comment: @harrymc Yep, the instructions for the HP UEFI fixed it. Thanks. Gonna write that up as an answer, since it's not eligible to be closed as duplicate unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment by [harrymc](https://superuser.com/users/8672/harrymc), the issue was resolved by following the instructions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1103331/11316), quote:

> In those cases, there is no option to choose a trusted UEFI file,
> however, there exists the option for a <kbd>Customized Boot</kbd>
> under the <kbd>Boot Options</kbd> menu. You have to add custom boot
> path and enter `EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`. Then you have to change the
> boot priority and put <kbd>Customized Boot</kbd> on top of the list
> for <kbd>UEFI Boot Order</kbd>.

So:

1. power on the laptop
2. hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>
3. once the options show up hit <kbd>F10</kbd> and enter the password, if prompted
4. In the <kbd>System Configuration</kbd> tab select <kbd>Boot Options</kbd> and navigate down to <kbd>Define Customized Boot Option</kbd> and select <kbd>Add</kbd>, then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. Enter the path to the UEFI/GRUB shim: `EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save
6. Navigate back up to <kbd>UEFI Boot Order</kbd> and place <kbd>Customized Boot</kbd> at the top of the list by selecting it (<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>) and pressing <kbd>+</kbd> once there to move it up one by one
7. save the settings when leaving the UEFI/BIOS setup

Next boot should work without said error message.

NB: In case you cannot change the mentioned settings or they aren't visible, check that a.) you are logged on as supervisor/admin in the UEFI/BIOS setup and b.) that the security settings allow you to *change* the given setting (it's a long list that allows: change, view, hide).